# Combination from arbitrary number of type of items

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations

Suppose we have $K$ number of items and the probability of picking item $k\in \{1,\dots,K\}$ equals $p_k$ (with $\sum_{k=1}^K p_k =1$). Let $n$ be an arbitrary number, then what is the probability that for each $k$ we have picked exactly $a_k$ items, with $\sum_{k=1}^K a_k = n$? Is this some known quantity like $\binom{n}{k}$?

Comment: you didnt mention how many items we are picking ?

Comment: We pick $n$ items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that $n$ is the number of trials (picked items) the probability in question is:
$$
n!\prod_{k=1}^K\frac{p_k^{a_k}}{a_k!}.
$$

Comment: O, I see! This is actually also equal to $\binom{a_1,\dots,a_K}{n} \prod_{k=1}^K p_k^{a_k}$ where we use the Multinomial Coefficients: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem#Ways_to_put_objects_into_bins

Comment: @Darkwizie Usually the multinomial coefficient is written as $\binom{n}{a_1,\dots a_K}$.

Comment: Yes, I made a mistake in my LaTeX code!